# Which Rust library is recommended if I would like to implement PLONK?

Tags: implementation, snarks, zero-knowledge

I think it should have APIs for polynomials, FFT and bilinear mapping if KZG commitment scheme is used.

Comment: What about on-chain implementation in Solidity?

Answer (score 1):

You should also look if you want to use it with something more. For example, if you want to use Poseidon Hash, [dusk-network](https://github.com/dusk-network/plonk) is useful as they have their own implementation of Poseidon.

In general, I found [dusk-network](https://github.com/dusk-network/plonk) as well as [ZK-Garage](https://github.com/ZK-Garage/plonk) "friendly" to use. They have also examples and readable documentation.

A general list of implementations can be found [here](https://hackmd.io/@mimoo/B1uIXu6G5).

edit: Now that I'm thinking about your question, you are asking a rust library to implement PLONK. My answer above contains libraries that implement PLONK. I will leave my answer in case you meant searching libraries that already implement PLONK or you are interested to see other implementations.